# what chages to make to get the question from dictionary

Tags: python

what changes to make to get the question form dictionary and then get the answer at the same time and check weather it is right or wrong

```
from random import *
print("""Welcom to the quiz game 
would you like to play?  """)
consent = input("-----> ")
consent = consent.lower()
if consent == "no":
    print("The game ends")
    quit()
else:
    print("Be redy to play")
    print("Answer the question in true and false")
points = 0
questions = ["Banana is a vegetable","Two plus two equals to four","Mumbai is the capital of present India","Tiger is an example of bird","punjab is a country"]
store = []
for ii in range(5):
    q1 = choice(questions)
    # q1.append(store)
    print(q1)
    ans1 = input("(True/False)----> ")
    ans1.lower()

    if q1 == questions[0] and ans1 == "false":
        points += 1
    if q1 == questions[1] and ans1 == "true":
        points += 1
    if q1 == questions[2] and ans1 == "false":
        points += 1
    if q1 == questions[3] and ans1 == "false":
        points += 1
    if q1 == questions[4] and ans1 == "false":
        points += 1

    print(f"your points are {points}")
```

tell some changes on this code to get that question from dictionarty and same answer at the runtime

Comment: What is `choice()`?

Comment: What dictionary are you referring to? I don't think you need a `dict`.

Comment: @JohnGordon due to him doing `from random import *` and not overwriting it, `choice==random.choice`

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary where the *key* is a question and the *value* is the answer:

```
quiz = {
    'This is a true question': 'true',
    'This is a false question': 'false',
    # and so on
}
```

Then choose a random question from the dictionary like this:

```
question = choice(list(quiz))
print(question)
```

And the correct answer will be `quiz[question]`.

```
answer = input("type the answer: ").lower()
if answer == quiz[question]:
    print("that is correct")
else:
    print("wrong answer")
```